# Child DIV Tag alignment using CSS with dynamic height

Tags: css

Aligning div tags vertically and horizontally is quiet easy to achieve but what I am looking for is something like the attached image where the height of the child div tag varies as per the content. I tried many things but cannot achieve the same behavior. Surely I am wrong somewhere.

Apologize if this is a duplicate post as I could not find anywhere.

Appreciate your guidance.

```css
#divContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#divContainer div.innerDIV {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  /*float: left;*/
  display: inline-flex; /* tried many other options */
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
  <div class="innerDIV">not much text here</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
</div>
```

Expected Outcome: [image]

Comment: `#divContainer { overflow: hidden }` to force it to wrap around your child divs?

Comment: @MarcB thanks tried but still the same..if you look at the expected, the child boxes are moved up compared to the current output

Comment: @JoshBurgess it will show div in straight vertical line and not what is expected.

Comment: closest i could get http://jsfiddle.net/v490udbb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using CSS columns:

```css
#divContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-columns: 200px 2;
  -moz-columns: 200px 2;
  columns: 200px 2 5px; }
#divContainer div.innerDIV {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
  <div class="innerDIV">not much text here</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="innerDIV">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks will try it.. will try to play around with number of columns may be to "auto" since the child div per row will depend on the screen size. Also, just a quick check, can the same column approach be used in hybrid mobile app HTML5 page (if you know)